# Class structure for a queue of variable size and type

Tags: c++

I'm more of a hardware person, but the chip design tools I'm using require me to write some C++ code. I am not familiar with object-oriented programming; although I have a good handle on C. What I'm asking is for an explanation of how to structure my class (called `cq`) to accomplish the task at hand.

I would like to be able to generate a queue of a specified data type and specified size (which should not change after being generated). Ideally, this would be accomplished like this...

```
my_queue = new cq(uint8_t, 6);
```

...which would generate an array (or vector) of six 8-bit unsigned integers.

Then, I would like a method to both insert an element to an end and return the element at the head of the queue as follows.

```
uint8_t front;
front = my_queue.advance(28);
```

What kind of structure do I need to accomplish this? Do I need a template since the data types are variable? Or should I have a generic class and have a class for each data type inherit its structure?

Thank you!

**Edit:** using input from the answers below, I've come up with the following:

```
template <class type>
template <class size>
class CQ {

    private:
        // Allocates a queue with type and size
        // specified by template arguments.
        std::queue<type> cycle_queue(size, 0);

    public:
        // Inserts input to the end of the queue;
        // removes and returns the front element.
        type advance(type in){
            type out = cycle_queue.front();
            cycle_queue.push_back(in);
            cycle_queue.pop_front();
            return out;
        }

}
```

My question then becomes... how do I instantiate this in my main C++ program? I tried this, but it did not work:

```
CQ<uint8_t><6> my_queue;
my_queue.advance(28);
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a perfect application for [STL containers.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/)  You could write your own queue class (as a template class, since you want to be able to specify data type), but why re-invent the wheel?

You're looking probably for: [`std::list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/), for a FIFO queue.  For your particular example:

```
std::list<uint8_t> my_queue;
my_queue.push_back(28);            // push an element
uint8_t front = my_queue.front();  // get the element on the front of the queue
my_queue.pop_front();              // and then pop it
```

---

If you're not already somewhat familiar with OOP and C++, writing your own template classes might be a bit out of reach for now.  There are good references all over the 'net though if you want to try: e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Comment: This does seem very attractive; however, does this solution maintain a constant size of the queue? When I start, I do not want it to be empty. I want it to be always have the length I specify and initialized to zero.

Comment: What happens, when you remove element from this container then?

Comment: @EvanW: so you want a fixed-size ringbuffer?

Comment: @sheu: not a ring, but fixed size, yes.

Comment: @EvanW: STL doesn't have a fixed-sized queue container, so you'll have to roll your own then.

Comment: @EvanW: oh, if all you care about is having it *initialized* to all 0, then you can just fill-construct it: `std::list<uint8_t> my_queue(6, 0)` will fill it with 6 '0' elements at initialization.  The length will change then as you push and pop from it, but that should be expected of any queue.

Comment: @sheu: that will work very well! I will only be pushing and popping at the same time, so the queue will remain constant in size. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `stl containers`, like `std::vector` (here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) or `std::list` (here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/). These collections already do what you want to achieve, your class would merely have to implement accessors to that collection.

The prototype would look like this:

```
std::vector Variable<uint8_t>;
```

Alternatively, you need to use `Templates`. A comprehensive explanation on what they are and how they work can be found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

In the essence, you would declare your object with

```
cq<uint8_t>(6);
```

And in the constructor you would put:

```
template <class T>
cq::cq(int amount) {
    Buffer = new T[amount];
}
```

Please do not forget to deallocate the memory once you're done with it with 'free'.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <queue>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::deque<int> myQueue;

    myQueue.push_back(1);
    myQueue.push_back(2);
    myQueue.push_back(3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int j = myQueue.front();
        printf("%d ", j);
        myQueue.pop_front();
    }

    getchar();
}
```

---

**Edit:** In response to comments

The easiest solution, that comes to my mind is:

```
myQueue.push_back(newValue);
while (myQueue.size > 6)
    myQueue.pop_front();
```

In fact, you can easily wrap this code in your own class, something like:

```
template <class T>
class SixItemsQueue
{
private:
    std::deque<T> data;

public:
    void Push(T value)
    {
        data.push_back(value);
        while (data.size() > 6)
            data.pop_front();
    }

    T Pop()
    {
        T result = data.front();
        data.pop_front();
        return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: This does seem very attractive; however, does this solution maintain a constant size of the queue? When I start, I do not want it to be empty. I want it to be always have the length I specify and initialized to zero.

Comment: Why do you want it to be of constant size? The std::deque is implemented in such way to be as efficient in adding and removing elements as possible.

Comment: I need this queue to store inputs so that I can compare the output of the circuit to be tested with inputs from a previous cycle. For instance, if my circuit took in inputs and generated a valid input 6 cycles later, I would need a queue of length 6 to store the inputs for the last six cycles. When the element is dequeued, I can then compare it with the output since I know it was my input six cycles ago.

Comment: thank you for showing me how to wrap this into a class; however, I'm wondering if it's possible to have a class that would work with _any_ data type and _any_ specified queue size.